# Mecha Anime from the 80s or 90s where the main character is a cop or detective

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I am looking for the old Mecha anime from the 80s or maybe 90s. I vaguely remember the main character is a cop or detective some sort. The opening he was chasing some guys and some how he got suck into the future, and then he team up with the people from the future to fight a organization, he can suit up a armor suit in a car.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should check out the [suggestions for anime-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) and the general [suggestions for story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember any additional details to [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you be looking for *[Mirai Keisatsu Urashiman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirai_Keisatsu_Urashiman)*, also known by its dub name of *Rock'n Cop*?

> The story tells of a young man and his cat who are being pursued by the police during a particularly stormy night in a city in 1983. The young man suddenly drives his car right into the middle of a cyclone and is caught in a space/time anomaly. As a result, they end up in the year 2050.
>
> Suffering from complete memory loss, he soon finds that he is being pursued by the army-like forces of Necrime, a top criminal organization led by Ludovich. Taking the name Ryū Urashima, the young man joins the police force and fights back against Necrime. He is joined in the fight by Sophia, a happy-go-lucky ex-nun, and Claude, a fellow officer. The unit is run by Inspector Gondo Toru. He is also joined by his cat, Myaa, whom made the time journey with him and is one of the few links to his past that he remembers.

### Intro

Found with a search for *anime officer chasing criminal pulled into future*

Comment: Yeah this the show thank for helping me. So he was being chasing by the cop at the beginning not chasing some criminal lol. You’re a big help.